# Issue Pulling a String through a Function

Tags: r, function, syntax, ggplot2

So my code is mostly good to go, the issue comes with this part at the end:

```
sqlPlot <- sqlPlot + facet_wrap(~variable)
```

This is happening because the variable that I am pulling through is a string and is not compatible with the facet_wrap() segment of my code.

My question is, how can I change the syntax so that it will work? I've tried researching how to address this issue, but since I am fairly new to R, I am not entirely sure how to even ask the question. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

```
library(sqldf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
```

sqldfGraphFn <- function(variable)
     {
     colNames <- paste("select ", get(variable), ", FYFQ, Date, sum(Revenue), sum(Quantity),", 
                       "sum(Revenue*Discount)/sum(Revenue)", sep="")
     from <- " from cleanData"
     groupBy <- paste(" group by ", get(variable), ", FYFQ, Date", sep="")
     sqlEverything <- paste(colNames, from, groupBy, sep="")
     sqlTest <- sqldf(sqlEverything)

`colnames(sqlTest)[which(colnames(sqlTest)=="sum(Revenue*Discount)/sum(Revenue)")] <- "wtCOGs"

 arguments <- as.list(match.call())
 variable = eval(arguments$variable, sqlTest)
 sqlPlot <- ggplot(data=sqlTest, aes(x=weightedDiscount, y=SLC)) + geom_point()
 sqlPlot <- sqlPlot + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-.05, .05), breaks=(-10:10)/200) + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 1000000))
 sqlPlot <- sqlPlot + facet_wrap(~variable)
 sqlPlot
 }

sqldfGraphFn("CarType")`

Comment: Normally one use `fn$sqldf` rather than paste to interpolate strings.  See examples on sqldf home page.  Please provide complete reproducible code including all inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create formula objects out of strings, so:

```
variable <- 'CarType'
myFormula <- as.formula(paste0('~', variable))

...

sqlPlot + facet_wrap(myFormula)
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much, I

Comment: @Yosarion Happy to help! Consider marking my answer as correct ;)